# encode opencv mat to gif using giflib

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel, gif, mat

I'm trying to encode some Mats into a gif file using giflib, but I can't get it to work.

Here's how I convert the opencv mat's data into gif pixel:

```
cv::resize(input_mat, input_mat, cv::Size (160, 160));
cv::Mat mrgba(160, gif_size, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0,0,0,0));
cv::cvtColor(input_mat, mrgba, CV_BGR2RGBA);
Byte * buffer = malloc( 160 * 160 *sizeof(Byte));
memcpy(buffer, mrgba.data, 160 * 160 *sizeof(Byte));
```

Then encode buffer into gif file. The other part of my code is right because I can use it to encode pixel buffers I got from OpenGL by using `glReadPixel`. I think maybe there's something wrong with OpenCV mat's data structure.

Let me attach a picture to show you what I got now:

[image]

Comment: what is ' input' ? why is 'input_mat' never used ?

Comment: @berak sorry, `input` is a typo, it should be `input_mat`. I'm resizing `input_mat` and then convert it RGBA color space. Then copy its data to `buffer`

Comment: in that case, you're not copying enough bytes. BGRA has 4 bytes per pixel, so you have to malloc and copy 4 x 160 x 160 bytes

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME! That is the reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @berak said, I was not copying enough bytes. the current size should be

```
memcpy(buffer, mrgba.data, 160 * 160 *sizeof(Byte));
```